# mongodump cant resolve host

Tags: database, mongodb, dump, mongodump

I'm using mongodb 3.4(.7) official docker image.
when I run mongodump with ip on remote host everything works fine,
but when I run mongodump with hostname it does not work and I get following error :

```
Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers.
```

and also when I ping hostname it resolves hostname to ip . so I think it's not dns issue.

first command (which works):

```
mongodump '--host' '127.0.0.1' '--port' '27017' '--username' '' '--password' '' '--authenticationDatabase' 'admin' '--out' '/var/www/storage/app/backup/all-2017-10-02-122911/digipeyk' '--oplog'
```

second command (which gives error):

```
mongodump '--host' 'digiserver_db' '--port' '27017' '--username' '' '--password' '' '--authenticationDatabase' 'admin' '--out' '/var/www/storage/app/backup/all-2017-10-02-122911/digipeyk' '--oplog'
```

I again repeat

```
ping digiserver_db
```

resolves the hostname to ip correctly.

the most odd thing is the following command also work :)

```
mongo '--host' 'digiserver_db' '--port' '27017'
```

and after executing the above command I'm in remote mongodb shell.

Answer (score 0):

```
mongodump --username webdevil --db webdevildb --authenticationDatabase admin  --password "123123"  --out /your/specific/path
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer to show what changes and **how** it fixes the issue in the question.